# login with facebook api with users account that have Suspended email

Tags: php, facebook, email, laravel

i try to login with facebook api in my application with laravel framework and it work well with most user but i note that some users with Suspended facebook email have problem in login because my code return error an empty email 
that is my code

```
Route::get('login/fb', function() {
$facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
$params = array(
    'redirect_uri' => url('/login/fb/callback'),
    'scope' => 'email,status_update,user_friends,publish_stream,user_birthday,manage_notifications',
    'display'=>'popup'
);
return Redirect::to($facebook->getLoginUrl($params));
});

Route::get('login/fb/callback', function() {

$code = Input::get('code');
if (strlen($code) == 0) return Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'There was an error communicating with Facebook');

$facebook = new Facebook(Config::get('facebook'));
$uid = $facebook->getUser();
if($uid){
       $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
       $facebook->setAccessToken($access_token);
        try{
           $me = $facebook->api("/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,email");
        } catch(Exception $e){
          echo $e->getMessage();
        }
}else{
    $params = array(
        'redirect_uri' => url('/login/fb/callback'),
        'scope' => 'email,status_update,user_friends,publish_stream,user_birthday,manage_notifications',
        'display'=>'popup'
    );
    return Redirect::to($facebook->getLoginUrl($params));
}
```

echo $me['email'];

> will return undefined index email with Suspended emails only 
>   how to avoid that problem

Comment: Not all Facebook users have an email so you need to make your code handle that

Comment: i know that but what can i do to avoid that problem !!